# Delphi StringGrid displayed with unwanted column spacing

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, stringgrid

Delphi TStringGrid is displayed incorrectly (with unwanted column spacing) in Embracedero Delphi 10.4. I tried everything in settings - disabled margins, disable Ctl3D, font settings, ... - I also tried creating a totally new StringGrid, but there is still a problem with column spacing.

Code to reproduce:

```
procedure TForm5.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if ARow = 0 then
  begin
    StringGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := $808080;
    StringGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect)
  end;
end;
```

[image: Unwanted column spacing example in Delphi StringGrid]

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue that the cell's `Rect.Left` in the `OnDrawCell` event of a `TStringGrid` is offset by 4 pixels. Probably (but not documented) to make it more easy to output text data, which requires a small offset from the border of the cell.

Note that the `TDrawGrid` does not have this offset.

For background painting of a cell you can use the `CellRect()` function

```
procedure TForm5.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  with Sender as TStringGrid do
  begin
    if ARow = 0 then
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := $C0C0C0;
      Canvas.FillRect(CellRect(ACol, ARow));
    end;

    // text output using `Rect` follows
    // ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Rather than offsetting the Rect manually, you can use the grid’s [`CellRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.CellRect) method instead.

Comment: @Remy Modified as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped a TStringGrid on the form and assigned an OnDrawCell event with the code you showed but this doesn't reproduce your issue exactly: I get only one pixel not drawn between cells.

To fix it, I enlarged the rectangle width and height by one pixel:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
    Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
    R : TRect;
begin
    R := Rect;
    Inc(R.Right);
    Inc(R.Bottom);
    if ARow = 0 then
        StringGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := $808080
    else
        StringGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := $A0A0A0;

    StringGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(R)
end;
```

As you can see, I added a check to paint rows greater that 0 to see the same behavior in the row direction.